# Find dy/dx given $y = {1 \over {1 + \sqrt x }}$, using the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is what I tried:

$$ {1 \over {1 + \sqrt x }} = {1 \over {\sqrt {1 + x} }} = {1 \over {{{(1 + x)}^{{1 \over 2}}}}} = {(1 + x)^{ - {1 \over 2}}} $$
$${{dy} \over {dx}} =  - {1 \over 2}{(1 + x)^{ - {3 \over 2}}}(1) = {{ - 1} \over {2{{(1 + x)}^{{3 \over 2}}}}}$$

This is the wrong answer, I'm certain I've made a mistake in interpreting or applying the chain rule.

If anyone could point out where I've went wrong in my approach that would be great, thank you.

Comment: Additionally, when you work on a problem like this, either as homework or as an examination question, always take a deep breath and think before you write. The most common mistake one can make is the *Freshman's Universal Distributive Law*. Except for the few uses in ordinary arithmetic or algebra, operations do not distribute. Substitute numbers other than $0$ or $1$ and you'll see.  $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \ne a + b$.  $\sin xy \ne \sin x \sin y$. And so on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem was not in the application of the chain rule; the problem is in the following:

> $\eqalign{
>  {1 \over {1 + \sqrt x }} \quad \overset{\color{red}{\bf \Large \checkmark }}= \quad {1 \over {\sqrt {1 + x} }} = {1 \over {{{(1 + x)}^{{1 \over 2}}}}}  \cr }$

That is,  $$\frac{1}{1 + \sqrt x} \neq \frac{1}{(1+x)^{1\over 2}}$$

Since you used an non-equivalent function, although your application of the chain-rule on the incorrect function was correct, it was not the derivative of the given function.

If we let $\color{green}{\bf \;u = (1 + \sqrt x)},\;$ then $\;\color{blue}{\bf\dfrac{du}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt x}}$.

Then we have the function $\quad y = \dfrac 1u = u^{-1}.\;$ $\color{red}{\bf \dfrac{dy}{du}} = -u^{-2} = \color{red}{\bf \dfrac{-1}{ u^2}}.\;$ The derivative of the function is $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \color{red}{\bf \frac{dy}{du}} \cdot \color{blue}{\bf \dfrac{du}{dx}} = \color{red}{\bf \frac{-1}{u^{2}}}\cdot \color{blue}{\bf \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}} = \dfrac{-1}{\color{green}{\bf(1+\sqrt x)}^2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt x} = \dfrac{-1}{2\sqrt x(1+\sqrt x)^2}$$

Comment: Very clear explanation of the issue +1

Comment: @amWhy I can see how the chain rule is applicable here now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

$$1+\sqrt{x} \ne \sqrt{1+x}$$

Rather,

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}} = -\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2} \frac{d}{dx}(1+\sqrt{x})$$

Comment: Could you explain how you reached the answer please?

Comment: Chain rule: $(d/dx) f(u)$ when $u=g(x)$ is $(df/du) (dg/dx)$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's go step by step. We are given the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}}$$

The chain rule is used to differentiate compositions. So let's write this as a composition? Well, i'll define the function $g: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ by:

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$$

And define the function $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $h(x) = \sqrt{x}$. It turns out pretty trivially that we must have $f = g \circ h$ because:

$$f(x)=g(h(x))=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}}$$

Now, it's just application of the chain rule, we get the following:

$$f'(x)=g'(h(x))h'(x)$$

Now it's just computation, you know that $g'(h(x))$ is just about differentiating $g$ and applying at $h(x)$, so that we get:

$$g'(h(x))=\frac{-1}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}$$

$$h'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

So the derivative of $f$ at $x$ must be:

$$f'(x)=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{x}(1+\sqrt{x})^2}$$

Now, this kind of thing, making everything explicit, defining each function, writing down the derivatives, and writing down the composition, is something that we only do in a few examples to understand what's the idea behind. Once you understood, do it on your mind. I hope this detailed example helps you out.

Comment: Dammit! I was just about to post that! :) Nice one!

Comment: Just looked over this again, nice answer, thank you!

Comment: May I ask what book you'd recommend learning from? I haven't really seen this approach in any of the books I've used..

Comment: @Assad, I would recommend you Spivak's Calculus. It's a rigorous book (even considered introductory to analysis), but it's a good book to get started with this kind of approach. Good luck!